# Looking for the professional video editing tool

Tags: video, software-rec, video-editing

No this is not a poll. I guess you have to admit that gimp is
*the* picture editing tool for linux. Well i am lookin for *the* video editing tool for linux. Is there one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for opensource professional level software unfortunately currently there is nothing like that.

We're all waiting for [lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) gnu/linux port. It'll be opensource. They [announced](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=19&id=36286&Itemid=81) about public beta 3 months ago, but still nothing was published. Hope it'll be available soon.

However, there are some a little bit amateur level software:

- kdenlive
- pitivi
- openshot
- kino

and others. Anyway it's much better to look the full list at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_editing_software) page and just google about some interesting positions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LWM](http://lwm.net), it has discussed several packages for video editing in the "Grumpy Editor" series (and elsewwhere) over time. Sadly, it is as rush says, they are all far from easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, looks like [Cinelerra GG](https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/) is what you're looking for.